# How to make diagonal guides in sketch 3?

Tags: sketch-app, guides

Sketch 3 is a great vector tool. However, it doesn't appear to support diagonal guides. Any work arounds?

Here is an [Illustrator workaround](http://veerle.duoh.com/design/article/create_diagonal_guidelines_in_illustrator).

Answer (score 1):

You can always just create a series lines using the line tool (L), color them similarly to your guides, and group (CMD + G) them together. That way you can easily toggle them on and off from your layers panel. (Lock them if you're worried about accidentally moving or editing them.) You can be pretty precise with angles as well. Draw a straight line and rotate it with the Rotate tool. Using the rotate tool allows you to adjust the origin. The main downside is no snapping to the "guide". But it's better than nothing. I haven't seen any plugins that would allow you to convert lines to guides either.

You can also send a feature request to Sketch through the app itself. Sketch > Feedback... There's a "feature request" option in the drop down. See if they plan on adding that in the future.